# Dump Just the table and reimport it - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dump, psql

Just as the title states, I have a table that has well over 25 million records and I need all those records. it will only grow over time, so I need to export this one table from a psql database and import it into another psql database which is used for development.

Ideas?

I know you can dump a whole database, but can you dump a table? (sorry if thats a dumb question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a backup of a single table in a postgres database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682866/how-to-create-a-backup-of-a-single-table-in-a-postgres-database)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$ pg_dump -d db -t big_table > big_table.sql
```