# Django relation "personindustry" does not exist

Tags: django

I have a below model,

```
class PersonIndustry(DFModel):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = ‘person_industry'
```

My postgres database contains person_industry table.

When I registered this model in admin site it is giving me below error,

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/apis/personindustry/
relation "personindustry" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM “personindustry"
```

I am quite confuse why it is searching for personindustry instead of person_industry. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem recently, what I did is:

```
# Clear migrations history
python manage.py migrate --fake APP_NAME zero
```

Then, delete the migrations files and **.pyc** files except for ****init**.py**. Now, make migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations APP_NAME
```

Now, fake the intial migrate. That will fake the intial table with name personindustry:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

*Note:- Feel free to ask. [Refs](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html)

Comment: My tables has lot of data in it. I don’t want to miss those. Does this method with impact the data?

Comment: I don't think that will effect the data, but I am not sure. Better make backup data. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682866/how-to-create-a-backup-of-a-single-table-in-a-postgres-database)

Answer (score 0):

My meta class was creating problem,

```
class DFModel(models.Model, metaclass=DFModelBase):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I changed it to default,

```
class PersonIndustry(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = ‘person_industry'
```

It is loading now.